# How can I get an image inside another div element to react on hover on the outermost div element?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a page where I have a Wordpress plugin WPDATATABLES using HTML to display some information that I'm pulling from various sites (importXML). The idea is for the page to look something like this https://www.labelradar.com/labels/chillyourmind/profile, that when you over over a particular element, the entire element reacts and changes into a white logo with the main color of the social media icon. Currently, I am able to get all the CSS working except for one small detail, and that's the white icon. It only changes when you are within range of the image outline of the icon.

Here's the page: https://trapparty.net/theparty/

I know there must be someway to force the div to react at the same time when I hover on the outermost div element controlling the entire thing. Here's a pastbin of the entire CSS code I'm using:

https://www.pastiebin.com/5cf313feb2753

And below is one HTML element with the nested DIV elements.

I've tried combining some CSS like this to try and call the div on the outside:

```
.soundcloud.soundcloudicon .soundcloudwhite {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

<center><a href="https://www.instagram.com/thetrapparty/" target="_blank"><div class="instagram"><div class="instagramicon">

<center><img src="https://www.trapparty.net/wp-content/followicons/instagram.png" height="263" width="178" alt="instagram">
        </center>
<center><img src="https://www.trapparty.net/wp-content/followicons/instagramwhite.png" height="263" width="178"  class="instagramwhite" alt="instagramwhite"></center>
    </div>
<div class="igcount"><h2><center><font color="white">47.4k</font></center></h2></div>
<div class="followerstextig">Followers</div></div></a></center>
```

The actual result I'd like can be seen in the Label Radar link above, but essentially, I want the white icon to show up whenever I hover over the entire  outer div element.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the title it would be something like:

```
div img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:hover img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this resolves the issue. Maybe you can expand on your thoughts? Thank you for you reply!